# как открыть страницу на новой вкладке при выполнении js с данными переданными через post

Tags: javascript, post

Здравствуйте.

При щелчке на элементе вызывается функция go

```
onChange='go(\"top_menu\", \"site\", \"l1\", \"$l1\");'
```

которая осуществляет передачу переменных через post для навигации по сайту

```
function go() { // передача переменных post
 var f = document.getElementById("id_form");
 for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    var name = arguments[i]
    i = i+1
    var value = arguments[i]
    var hid = document.createElement("input");
    hid.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hid.setAttribute("name", name);
    hid.value = value;
    f.appendChild(hid);
 }
 f.submit();
 return false;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы новая страница, на которую переходит пользователь в результате выполнения этого скрипта, открывалась на новой вкладке?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте форме в html атрибут [target](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/target)

```
<form target="_blank"  ...
```

Либо в js:

```
var f = document.getElementById("id_form");
f.setAtrribute('target', '_blank');
// ...
```